# ¿Cómo definir y utilizar un array bidimensional del cual desconozco dimensiones en C#?

Tags: c#, array, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Tengo la siguiente duda, en C# los arrays se definen así:

```
int[] myarray = new int[10];.
```

Ahora bien, si desconozco la dimensión del array puedo utilizar un Arraylist, por ejemplo:

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
```

y luego de llenarla lo recorro con un foreach. Mi duda es, hay algo similar pero para arrays bidimensionales?

Porque al definir una matriz así:

```
float[,] sumas = new float[10, 4];
```

Luego puedo recorrerlas con un for y utilizar la propiedad sumas.getLength, pero en mi caso no sé las dimensiones que tendrá la matriz bidimensional, desconozco la forma de definir y utilizar un arreglo con más de una dimensión en C#.

No se si se entiende la pregunta, cualquier cosa me dejan un comentario

Comment: Ayer te dije que usaras List... borraste tu pregunta, y usaste algo que en su documentacion dice: "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. " que no lo uses, y que uses List.. donde para definir una matriz, harias List<List<float>>

Comment: una matriz, no es mas que un array que es su interior contiene un array por posicion..  para el caso, definis tu arraylist, y dentro de cada posicion lo llenas con otro arraylist...

Comment: Y getLength no te da las dimensiones?, pq para eso ese metodo

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, estoy probando con el List<T>, y el getLength me da error y con el List no puedo usarlo

Comment: Entonces trabajemos sobre eso.. sobre tus errores en getLength y en como usar list... y mucho mejor, si usas list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece una buena oportunidad para aprender un poco acerca del net framework.

> pero en mi caso no sé las dimensiones que tendrá la matriz bidimensional, desconozco la forma de definir y utilizar un arreglo con más de una dimensión en C#.

El problema de las matrices cuyas dimensiones no se conocen de antemano ya fue solucionado, y fue solucionado con los [Generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics), más específicamente, con las [Generic Collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-5.0).

De acuerdo a la documentación: Una [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0) aumenta su tamaño automáticamente según sea necesario.

> The capacity of a List is the number of elements that the List can hold. As elements are added to a List, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array.
> If the size of the collection can be estimated, specifying the initial capacity eliminates the need to perform a number of resizing operations while adding elements to the List.

Puedes pegar este codigo en un proyecto de consola para probarlo.

```
var stringList = new List<string>();
          
Console.WriteLine("Tamaño de la lista cuando no hay elementos en ella: " 
+ stringList.Capacity); // 0
Console.WriteLine("Agregar una cadena.");

stringList.Add("A Fool's Paradise");
         
Console.WriteLine("Capacidad cuando añadimos un elemento: " + stringList.Capacity); // 4

Console.WriteLine("Agreguemos cuatro más.");
stringList.AddRange(
    new string[] {
        "The Divine Wings of Tragedy" ,
        "The Odyssey",
        "A Winter's Dream",
        "Nevermore" });
 Console.WriteLine("Capacidad nueva: " + stringList.Capacity); // 8
```

Por dentro, una `List<T>` es un `Array` simple y silvestre que automáticamente incrementa su tamaño a medida que se agregan elementos a ella. Entonces, si haces una **lista de listas** (`List<List<T>>`), por ejemplo, estás creando una matriz bidimensional, con un tamaño inicial [0,0], que irá creciendo automáticamente.

Si quieres en realidad ver como exactamente funciona la implementación de los Generics, puedes descompilar el .dll y verlo por ti mismo.

Ahora, si quieres inicializar las listas con una capacidad específica, `List<T>` [tiene un constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0) que acepta un `int32` como argumento para inicializarla con una capacidad específica

`public List (int capacity);`

Y, nuevamente, si quieres saber cuál es el tamaño del arreglo, en lugar de getLength, puedes utilizar `.Count` para obtener la cantidad de elementos en la lista, o `.Capacity` para saber cuál es el tamaño del arreglo interno.

### Finalmente, para responder a tu pregunta:

> ¿Cómo definir y utilizar un array bidimensional del cual desconozco dimensiones en C#?

Recomendamos que utilices:

`var arregloBidimensionalDeEnteros = new List<List<int>>();`

Porque la capacity será [0,0]. Y puedes utilizar for/foreach para llenar o leer ese arreglo.

Si **en realidad insistes** en crear un arreglo vacío... utiliza [Array.Empty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=net-5.0):

```
        var emptyArray = Array.Empty<string>(); // 
        Console.WriteLine("length del arreglo vacío: " +emptyArray.Length);
        emptyArray[0] = "Hola mundo";
        Console.WriteLine("length con el nuevo elemento: " + emptyArray.Length); // System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

PEEEERO, tendrás que manejar ese tipo de excepciones, donde tengas que crear un arreglo nuevo con un tamaño nuevo en caso que quieras agregar elementos. Y ese problema ya fue resuelto... Con `List<T>`...

Comment: entiendo, genial, muchas gracias, me aclara bastante el funcionamiento de los generic, probaré él código, gracias